# Receiving messages using a CAN adapter

Tags: c++, api, message, can-bus

I'm using a CAN adapter API for Visual C++ Express. You can find out more about the API at [their website](http://www.phytec.com/products/can/pc-can-interfaces/sysusb2.html). Click on the USB-CANmodul2 Hardware Manual for the correct PDF file I am using. This is useful for any program that uses CAN that needs a good API for it.

[My code](http://pastebin.com/JcipGK8Y)

Attached are some pictures to help describe what it is I am doing. I'm running a CAN bootloader on one compiler and my parsing program is on Visual Express. The parsing program should read from a text file and send parsed information to the CAN bootloader so it can program it to its memory. I am able to send messages fine. The problem is, when the CAN bootloader receives a message, it is supposed to reply to the other program that everything sent was correct, but I can't figure out how to receive messages in the parsing program with the API. I have done basically everything the their PDF file told me.

What am I doing wrong?

Pictures of the programs in debug mode:
The information from the parsing program sent, the bootloader is putting it into a buffer.
The bootloader is about to call functions to send a message back saying no error. The parsing program never gets past the polling loop, so it never receives the message. I know the bootloader sending functions worked, because I have tested them with the same CAN program the API comes in. Hopefully that is enough information for you guys to kind of understand what I am doing.

These are the lines I'm having trouble with:

```
             do
274.              retMessageF = UcanReadCanMsgEx(UcanHandle, &bChannel, &rxMessage, NULL);
275.         while(retMessageF != USBCAN_SUCCESSFUL);
```